# How can I reach google analytics datas?

Tags: php

My goal is to show google analytics datas on the header of my site. Thats all I have until now (its from googleApiPhPClient/examples/analytics:

```
require_once 'library/GoogleApiPhpClient/apiClient.php';
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=analytics to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
 $client->setClientId('aaa');
 $client->setClientSecret('bbb_gK');
 $client->setRedirectUri('ccc');
 $client->setDeveloperKey('dd');

require_once ('contrib/apiAnalyticsService.php');
$service = new apiAnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
  print "<h1>Web Properties</h1><pre>" . print_r($props, true) . "</pre>";

  $accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
  print "<h1>Accounts</h1><pre>" . print_r($accounts, true) . "</pre>";

  $segments = $service->management_segments->listManagementSegments();
  print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($segments, true) . "</pre>";

  $goals = $service->management_goals->listManagementGoals("~all", "~all", "~all");
  print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($goals, true) . "</pre>";

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

but this only drops a "connect me" link. Am in the somewhat right way on getting analytic datas anyway?

Comment: it may be asking you to do an oauth with google account. I've been using this http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/ which only requires the google account user name and password and works pretty well.

Comment: ok, thx Im trying to use your idea. I gave my GA code for requestReportData() method, but it fails...

Comment: a sample code of mine where im checking visits $ga->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,array('browser','browserVersion','country'),array('pageviews','visits'),null,"country==USA",$yesterday,$todate);

Comment: its ok, but how to get ga_profile_id?

Comment: when you log in to your account, select the profile you already made for your web site . when you will click it, the url would be like https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#report/visitors-overview/axxxxxxwxxxxxpxxxxx/ so the ga_profile_id would be the one written after "p" in the URL.. i see this way only to get this profile id.

Comment: ok, solved :) thx, pls send a "post" so that I can officially accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface which only requires the google account user name and password and works pretty well

```
a sample code of mine where im checking visits $ga->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,array('browser','browserVersion','country'‌​),array('pageviews','visits'),null,"country==USA",$yesterday,$todate);
```

when you log in to your account, select the profile you already made for your web site . when you will click it, the url would be like google.com/analytics/web/#report/visitors-overview/… so the ga_profile_id would be the one written after "p" in the URL.. i see this way only to get this profile id