# Google Analytics With PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google Analytics with php. I can't use javascript. Is there is any way around this?

I've tried some of php libraries but its seems these libs are not working.
Lib which i tried: http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this question with a sample code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797458/how-can-i-reach-google-analytics-datas/10799674#10799674 . Check this library : http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: in this we can get report only, can we update event or paageview tracking also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, google provides a server side code here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites

Which provides a basic functionality and works perfectly for page views. However, it does not include events or custom variables. What you can do is use this code along with some simple functions that will allow you to sent the right parameters (utme) into the gif request.